# When I try to follow the link localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/filesmap/my_mapfile.map I get errors that there is no access to map images

Tags: mapserver, apache

When I try to follow the link localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/filesmap/my_mapfile.map I get errors that there is no access to map images

I have an Ubuntu server on which a mapserver is running, I tried to set it up and in the end, every time I go to the link, I get similar errors, what should I do about it? How can I make it access the directory I need on the server, take images from there and display them?[image]

Comment: please show the actual URLs you use for the request as text **not** pictures, you probably also need to tell us how you set mapserver up and what is in the log file